# SolrJ how to change field type of a field defined by annotation?

Tags: solrj

I followed Solr [guide](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/using-solrj.html#java-object-binding) created a class and used @Field annotation in front of the class attributes.

```
public class MyDocument {

@Field
public String fra_contents;
... // Other fields
//NO getters and setters as shown https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_2/using-solrj.html#java-object-binding

}
```

Looking at the generated "managed-schema.xml" shows that "fra_contents" is of type "text_general" :

```
<field name="fra_contents" type="text_general"/>
```

Yet I need to apply a different tokenizer, and different filters to this field than the ones associated with "text_general". So I created a fieldtype **programmatically** (following based on [Solr testing code](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=lucene-solr.git;a=blob;f=solr/solrj/src/test/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/request/SchemaTest.java;h=72051b123aadb2df57f4bf19abfedb0ac0deb6cd;hb=refs/heads/branch_7_4)) called "fra_contents_type" :

```
<fieldType name="fra_contents_type" class="solr.TextField">
<analyzer type="index">
  <tokenizer class="solr.ClassicTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.KeywordRepeatFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="lang/fra.txt"/>
  <filter class="solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.ElisionFilterFactory" articles="lang/contractions_fr.txt"/>
  <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="French"/>
  <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
  <tokenizer class="solr.ClassicTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.KeywordRepeatFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.ElisionFilterFactory" articles="lang/contractions_fr.txt"/>
  <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="French"/>
  <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

This other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827709/how-do-solrj-pojo-java-types-map-to-solr-types) explains how the fieldtype is set based on the java variable type, but does not tell how to change this defauld fieldtype.

So how can I change the fieldtype of this field programmatically while keeping the annotation (ie without editing the "managed-schema.xml") ?

Any help appreciated,

Answer (score 0):

So here is what I found which works *a posteriori* and not *a priori* using the [Schema API](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/schema-api.html).

```
 // First retrieves the original field attributes
    SchemaRequest.Field originalField = new SchemaRequest.Field(fieldName);
    Map<String, Object> updatedFieldAttributes = originalField.process(
            getSolrClient()).getField();

    // Modifies the original attributes
    updatedFieldAttributes.put("type",
            fieldTypeName);

    // Updates the field type of the field
    SchemaRequest.ReplaceField replaceFieldRequest = new 
    SchemaRequest.ReplaceField(updatedFieldAttributes);

    // Processes the requests
    List<SchemaRequest.Update> list = new ArrayList<>(3);
    list.add(addFieldTypeRequest);
    list.add(replaceFieldRequest);
    SchemaRequest.MultiUpdate multiUpdateRequest = new SchemaRequest.MultiUpdate(
            list);
    SchemaResponse.UpdateResponse multipleUpdatesResponse = multiUpdateRequest.process(
            getSolrClient());
```

There may be a cleaner way (aka "one liner" ;-) ) to do it!